# How to get the uib-popover to open or close when the focus of the input field changes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a input field that has the uib-popover control on it. I have followed the documentation on how to get the directive to open but I have noticed some discrepancies in the documentation as well as examples on plnker and SO questions here.

Within my hmtl I have the inputs set as follows:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                            <label>Password</label><input type="{{user.inputType}}" ng-blur="user.validatePassword(user.newUser.password, user.newUser.confirmPassword)" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password" required class="form-control" ng-model="user.newUser.password" uib-popover-template="'myPopoverTemplate.html'"  uib-popover-trigger="'focus'"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                            <label>Confirm Password</label>
                            <input type="{{user.inputType}}" ng-keyup="user.validatePassword(user.newUser.password, user.newUser.confirmPassword)" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirmPassword" required class="form-control" ng-model="user.newUser.confirmPassword"/>
                            <span style="color: red">{{user.message}}</span>
                        </div>
```

Most examples as well as the SO questions on here are using an older library as attributes are not prefaced with uib-*.

This code/directive currently works and renders but it only work or appears when clicking in the field and then clicking in the same field to close the popover. I have tried both the `focus` trigger and the `oustsideClick` trigger. Both have the same result of not rendering or closing the popover unless clicking in the field.

versions of the frameworks used are:

- angularjs 1.5.8
- ui-bootstrap 1.3.3

Changing the trigger to match earlier examples were  `popover-trigger` is used vs. `uib-popover-trigger` is used disables the popover
I have [created a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SoQkC4c5yeW55W0Ac8yu?p=preview) that demonstrates what is happening.

Any suggestions on what I am missing or what I need to change.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`tooltip.js`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/78559761dcbd3cb20cbd458b0e27a64de516c148/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L96,L99) description, in order to set a *custom* trigger,
it needs to be specified via  `trigger` option passed to the `$tooltipProvider.options` method. In your case for `focus` trigger it will be:

```
app.config(['$uibTooltipProvider', function ($uibTooltipProvider) {
    $uibTooltipProvider.options({ trigger: 'focus' });
  }]);
```

Updated [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/nJTKp2jjdencO59otxnA?p=preview)  that shows how to trigger tooltip on `focus` handler.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem of your code, please modify like below:

**app.js**:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller('main',[ '$scope', main]);
    function main($scope)
    {
      vm = this;

      vm.message = 'hello';

      vm.dynamicPopover = {
        content: 'Hello, World!',
        templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',
        title: 'Title'
      };
    }

}());
```

**index.html**

```
<input class="form-control" uib-popover-template="vm.dynamicPopover.templateUrl"  popover-trigger="focus"/>
```

Actually, you can not just pass the template's id to the `uib-popover-template` attribute, you need to create an object to map it waited to pass.